# What are the pros and cons of ia32-libs?

Tags: linux-mint, 64bit

On my working install of Linux (Mint 17), I've been trying to avoid installing the `ia32-libs` package.
When I've used it in the past, I recall a number of issues arising, most prominently significantly slower boot times and some Cinnamon settings being broken.

I note that the Linux Mint 17.1 upgrade [requires `ia32-libs` for Skype](http://www.linuxmint.com/rel_rebecca_cinnamon.php) (which I would like to keep using).
This is one major reason that I'm not yet upgrading.

What are the actual pros and cons of the `ia32-libs` package?
Is it "deprecated" in the sense that new applications are probably going to be 64-bit native, so I might be able to avoid downloading ever? Or am I just delaying the inevitable?

Answer (score 3):

ia32-libs allows you to install common 32-bit programs, no more, no less. It's a collection of 32-bit libraries. It has no impact on 64-bit programs. It doesn't hurt performance, all it does is take up a bit of disk space.

Newer versions of Debian and Ubuntu have made ia32-libs obsolete by allowing 32-bit packages to be installed on a 64-bit system, so you can pick exactly the libraries that you need. This is called [multiarch](http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/). Mint 17 is multiarch, so you can install individual 32-bit libraries by installing the `i386` version of the same package name as the 64-bit library, e.g. `apt-get install libc6:i386`. You may need to enable multiarch (I don't know if the installer does it for you) by running sudo `dpkg --add-architecture i386` once and for all (then update the package list with `apt-get update` before you can start installing 32-bit packages).

The `ia32-libs` package is still provided for backward compatibility in case you have third-party deb packages that declare a dependency on that package name, and to facilitate the installation of a large selection of common libraries in case you have a manually installed binary and don't want to spend time selecting the exact set of packages you need to get the libraries it requires.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. [This 2013 thread](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=122296) on LM forums says that if `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` prints "i386" (which it does on my box) then "there's no more action to take." Do you agree with this/does it make sense? What would it look like were Mint to make the transition to multiarch?

Comment: @WChargin That was my mistake, due to not being familiar with Mint releases. Mint actually became multiarch several versions ago. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

32 bit binaries are generally smaller faster in any form.  same for libs.  the implication is the newer version of skype is 32 bit.  Better question is how your kernel handles 32 bit addressing, or if it does at all.  Next would be the hardware  your running on.  After that would be its purpose.  Does it matter if it boots slow or do you just want to know why. In the time it takes to answer one of these questions debian has changed the purpose and implementation of the other three.  Perhaps its better not to know so long as it works.  It is not a easy answer but in the end if you don't like what you get you should be compiling and packaging these pkg's from source and deploying them yourself instead of asking what some one else happens to be doing today at this moment.  You will be more satisfied with the end result.

Answer (score 0):

Personal experience as a datapoint (a con):

apt-get install ia32-libs on Linux Mint 19 Tara xfce bricked the graphics beyond usage: desktop items and GUI items are drawn slowly, or not at all.

After sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove ia32-libs, the problem persists. My solution is to reinstall the OS.

Please be careful.