# Install 32 Bit Application on 64 Bit Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, 64bit, pacman, libreoffice, 32bit

I have an ancient openoffice plugin which requires the 32bit version of openoffice/libreoffice and does not work with the 64 bit version. So I would like to know, if there is any way to install the 32bit version of libreoffice on a standard 64 bit multilib enabled Arch Linux with pacman?

In the past I placed an 32 bit version manually somewhere in the filesystem, but that is more or less only a workaround and has several disadvantages.

Comment: There is no official way to do this, but you can definitely take the official PKGBUILD for libreoffice and modify it to install the 32-bit version. This is a limitation of multilib as compared to how some other distros handle multiple architectures, and there are some attempts being made to improve this in the future.

Comment: Have a look at this article: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179902/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-ia32-libs . Edit: Sorry, didn't realise that this is a very old question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use a Docker container, or would be if 32-bit containers were easier to find.

There's an official minimal ArchLinux image [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/base/archlinux/), but since it doesn't say otherwise, and this is 2016, I'd assume it's 64-bit. However, it does show the script that was used to create the image, so it probably wouldn't be much work to add the options that switch the architecture.

Once you have a minimal image then installing LibreOffice would be straight-forward, using pacman. Running X applications inside a container is slightly tricky, but should work as long as you use `--net=host` and `-v /home/USER:/home:USER` when you create the container, and use the same username/user-id inside the container as outside.